# Criterion to check differentiability at the origin.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f( \Theta) = 0 $, where $\Theta = (0,...,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Also, suppose $f(x) \leq ||x||^2 $, then $f$ must be differentiable at the origin.

MY try:

Notice

$$ 0 \leq \frac{ f(h) }{||h||} \leq ||h|| $$

$$ \therefore \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f( \Theta + h) - f( \Theta) }{||h|| } = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{||h||} = 0 $$

by squeeze rule, hence the limit exists and is the derivative of $f$ at the origin. Hence, $f$ must be differentiable at the origin.
Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what you have done is right.